# How to eliminate the duplicate try-catch code in similar methods?

Tags: java, refactoring, code-duplication

I have the following insert/update methods in my service:

```java
@Override
public void insertEntity(Entity entity) {

  try {        
    entityDao.insert(entityMapper.entityToEntityDO(entity));

  } catch (DataIntegrityViolationException ex){

    if(ex.getCause() instanceof SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException) {
      SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException violationEx = (SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException) ex.getCause();
      if(violationEx.getErrorCode() == 1048 && "23000".equals(violationEx.getSQLState())) {
        throw new FieldCannotBeNullException(violationEx.getMessage());
      }
    }

    throw ex;
  }
}

@Override
public void updateEntity(Entity entity) {

  try {        
    entityDao.update(entityMapper.entityToEntityDO(entity));

  } catch (DataIntegrityViolationException ex){

    if(ex.getCause() instanceof SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException) {
      SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException violationEx = (SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException) ex.getCause();
      if(violationEx.getErrorCode() == 1048 && "23000".equals(violationEx.getSQLState())) {
        throw new FieldCannotBeNullException(violationEx.getMessage());
      }
    }

    throw ex;
  }
}
```

As you can see, the actual logic of `insertEntity` and `updateEntity` is very simple. In order to throw a custom `Exception`, I did some database error code check. Since the two methods all need this kind of checking, the code duplicated in both methods, which is obviously a code smell.

How can I eliminate this kind of code duplication?

Comment: Looking at the `@Override` annotations: Is Java 8 used, what is the super-class or implemented interface that has the `updateEntity` and `insertEntity`-methods?

Comment: I would just put the code in the catch block(s) to a separate method.

Comment: You might consider moving away from exceptions as a way to control flow. I image you are doing more than just checking for null columns - so the code which calls these methods has a lot of exception handling to  do. That's idiomatic in Java, but not particularly readable, or efficient...

Answer (score 2):

Extract the common catch-block to a method which throws `DataIntegrityViolationException`.

Answer (score 1):

You can create Interface like this:

```
public interface ConsumerWithException<T, V extends Exception> {
    /**
     * Performs this operation on the given argument.
     *
     * @param t the input argument
     */
    void accept(T t) throws V;

}
```

Use it a private method like:

```
private void action(ConsumerWithException<Entity, DataIntegrityViolationException> doAction, Entity entity){
    try {
        doAction.accept(entity);
    } catch (DataIntegrityViolationException ex){

        if(ex.getCause() instanceof SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException) {
            SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException violationEx = (SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException) ex.getCause();
            if(violationEx.getErrorCode() == 1048 && "23000".equals(violationEx.getSQLState())) {
                throw new FieldCannotBeNullException(violationEx.getMessage());
            }
        }

        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put the code inside the catch block into a separate method.

Alternatively, You can catch `Exception` and write a handler method to handle the exceptions if in future you expect to handle multiple exceptions there.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare your methods to throw the exception, then try/catch in one place where your methods are called. For example:

```
public void insertEntity(Entity entity) throws DataIntegrityViolationException {} 
public void updateEntity(Entity entity) throws DataIntegrityViolationException {}  
try {
  insertEntity(entity);
  updateEntity(entity);
catch (DataIntegrityViolationException e) {
  // handle exception
}
```